# How do I change the selected item colour using Styles?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-styles

I have a `Android 5` device and I set up some `Material Styles` using this blog:[Material Design Theming for Xamarin.Forms Android Apps](http://motzcod.es/post/115523285992/material-design-theming-for-xamarinforms-android) and got this theme:

**Values-v21\styles.xml**

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Values\colors.xml**

```
<resources>
  <color name="color_primary">#404040</color>
  <color name="color_primary_dark">#404040</color>
  <color name="accent">#379ADE</color>
</resources>
```

This works fine.. BUT.. I cant seem to work out why my selected item is appearing **orange?**

[image]

How do I change the color of my selected item using `Styles`.. Where is the **Orange** coming from?

**Ps.** if I remove the Styles it returns to the default blue.

I also found [Android Color Control Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/boxme/1fec2a44cc46fad221ee) but can't see an entry to change listview selected item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're having Xamarin.Forms Styles and Android resources mixed up.

In Xamarin.Forms you can change the color based on a property change like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/triggers/):

```
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <Style TargetType="Entry"> 
       <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger TargetType="Entry" Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
         </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </ResourceDictionary>
```

You may want to define your colors Xamarin.Forms `<ResourceDictionary>` (not Android `<resource>`) and maybe populate the dictionary on startup time from platform-specific resources.

A general side note: when using Xamarin.Forms really focus on your app's functionality in a platform-independent manner; from experience I can say it's difficult and messy to retroactively make the app platform-independent when you've taken subtle dependencies on the platform, such as colors, sizes, UI paradigms etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I'm not sure it works for me. My Android styles are there to customise the toolbar but for some reason also customise selected item. My item I'm selecting is a listviewitem and I can't see how to add an implicit style to my resourcedictionary for that

Comment: It's got to be something to do with: `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` as removing individual items doesn't change anything but removing the entire style works

Comment: have you tried to apply an explicit style to your ListView to override the theme default? I'd still recommend to not focus on a particular flavor of underlying OS and focus more on the app itself. Or if you're focused on Android just use the Xamarin.Droid and not Forms, it's much cleaner

Comment: this works but the problem lies with Grid.IsFocused always being false regardless of whether it is focused

Comment: `Grid` is never focused because it's not a UI input element. `Focused` means it's the UI element currently being used to input